# Why didn't I get any bounty after the question was accepted?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

I have answered a question, and after the bounty expired, I didn't get any bounty.

And the bounty was started by the question owner,
the question owner accepted an answer during the bounty period, but the bounty award period expired without an explicit award.

So why?

Comment: Their is a 24 hour grace period, you should receive the bounty 24 hours after it ends.

Comment: @MarkKirby However after 24 hour, I still got no bounty, and the bounty is not displaying in the question page any more.

Comment: Link to question please.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59496745/undefined-property-stdclass-error-when-using-date-type-column-on-laravel-how/59497137#59497137

Comment: Your answer was posted before the bounty started, so it's not eligible for the auto award.

Comment: [Timeline for that bountied post](https://stackoverflow.com/POSTS/59496745/timeline)

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard  ok, thx.

Comment: @Luuklag yes, I found it "They were posted after the bounty was started"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the bountied [question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/POSTS/59496745/timeline), you have answered before the bounty started. Hence, you have not received the bounty.

> [image: timeline]

Answer (score 3):

It is up to the bounty owner to decide what to do about the bounty.

Sometimes they simply forget about it. *You* can't do anything about that. And as pointed out in comments: there is an additional grace period. Maybe the bounty owner simply wants to wait for the last minute before awarding the bounty. There is always a chance that another, better answer comes in. But it looks like the OP of that question just missed to award it.

It is sometimes helpful to write a polite comment to "not forget about awarding the bounty", but that is about it.

And yes, that leads to the fact that sometimes the bounty isn't awarded at all, because forgotten. But the system is designed like that on purpose (for answers given before the bounty was established).

---

<sub>And yes, that is a very annoying feeling. Happened to me twice that my accepted answer missed a bounty because "forgotten". Worst case, take it as one of those events in life that allow you to grow your personality.</sub>